# Java - JOptionPane error messages and info messages

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

My application has a lot of error messages. I'm wondering what the best way to manage them is, and what the most efficient standard of this is?

1. I include the JOptionPanes exactly where they are supposed to be run.
2. I create a method in the class for each JOptionPane which is to be run.
3. I create a class with many static methods, of which will be called to run the JOptionPane.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Avoid reliance on JOptionPane? Or create a definitive list of errors that can occur in your application? Might need more info but it sounds like it could be something a lot of developers have wrangled with ;].

Comment: I think he's talking about application error messages rather than compile time stuff. e.g. "Your account is overdrawn, no sweets for you today" etc.

Comment: @davidfrancis: yes, you are probably correct. I've deleted my comment. Apologies to Niles.

Comment: I basically have a load of methods at the moment which can be called to produce errors. It works I'm wondering whether this is inefficient and whether I should put the messages in their own class.

Answer (score 2):

The general solution is to:

1) extract the error message strings out to resources, so they're all in one place (resource file(s)) instead of in the code.  (this also makes them trivial to translate for internationalization)

2) create a class/facility/service that you call to show the error message.  this decouples the code that shows error messages from JOptionPane, and, if done properly, allows you to unit test the code to ensure you're getting the proper messages from the right places, and prevents modal dialogs from appearing during unit test runs.

Comment: +1, for keeping `String` Literals in resource files :-) . Wonderful explanation, as to how it helps in future :-)